# setState not updating inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, setstate

I have tried looking at similar questions here without any luck. I wonder if my problem is due to my ListView being inside a FutureBuilder which again is inside its own widget, which again is inside an alertdialog with its own statefulbuilder.

I am trying to change the color of a button inside a listview after it is pressed.

The color is updated, but I have to rerender the alertdialog/listview to see the changes.

I removed a good portion of irrelevant code to make it readable and more easy to see the structure.

The structure of the code is as follows:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
 bool test = false; //Bool controlling the color of the button


_showDialog1(chosenTitle, choice) { //Function to trigger dialog
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) { //StatefulBuilder placed because thats what I thought was needed for my project to work.
        return AlertDialog(
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: choice,
            ),}})})


Widget hamburgerValue(value) { //THIS is the widget placed in the "choice" parameter above
    var _messageController = TextEditingController();

    List<dynamic> privSessions = [];
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Wrap(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
                        child: Text('Placeholder'),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 30.0),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          width: 300,
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _messageController,
                            maxLines: 5,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                //labelText: 'Din melding her',
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                hintText: 'Din melding her'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 300,
                    child: Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: privSessions.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                            bool test = false; //VARIABLE TO DETERMINE COLOR CHANGE
                            if (i == 0) {
                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  Text(privSessions[i]['day'],
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      datoFull,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: privSessions[i]
                                              ['available']
                                          ? () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                test = true; //WHERE THE SETSTATE HAPPENS
                                              });
                                            }
                                          : null,
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                          primary: test
                                              ? Colors.red
                                              : Colors.cyan),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(time,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white)),
                                        ],
                                      ))
                                ],
                              );
                            }
```

Comment: Can you include full widget?

Comment: Separate your ListView inside`hamburgerValue` as a StatefulWidget in its own file so that its state changes is restricted to it.